# Advice to go from MATLAB .mat file with structures to a numpy array?

Tags: python, matlab, pytorch, torch

I am trying to read in a large structure from a .mat file into a jupyter notebook. I am a little new to python so I'm not sure why my solution isn't working.

The structure from MATLAB(2020) I am reading in is structured like this

```
pose.frames.ind
```

Where there are 44 frames and in each frame 63 ind. I am reading it into a jupyter notebook like this with mat4py. I am trying to adapt someone else's code so after I read it in I need to convert it to a tensor so it can go into another function.

```
from mat4py import loadmat
val = loadmat('pose.mat')
pose_body = val['pose']['frames']['ind'][0]
pose_body = np.asarray(pose_body)
pose_body = torch.FloatTensor(pose_body).to(comp_device)
```

When I feed `pose_body = np.zeros([1,63])` into the line that changes it to a torch tensor, the code works fine. However, when I try to feed it this array I imported something goes wrong and I get the error of

**RuntimeError: invalid argument 0: Tensors must have same number of dimensions: got 2 and 1 at C:/w/1/s/tmp_conda_3.7_055306/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1556690124416/work/aten/src\THC/generic/THCTensorMath.cu:62**

Is there an easier/better way to convert the data from matlab in the format I need? I am a little unfamiliar with python, and it seems like they're the same type of array. From doing `type(pose_body), and tf.size(pose_body)` I know that both numpy arrays have a shape of 63, a dtype of int32, and are of class "numpy.ndarray".

Comment: It's probably because a 1D "tensor" doesn't exist in matlab, and you need squeeze then shape accordingly for whatever pytorch thing you're doing. Unfortunately, without a reproducible example there's really no way to help much.

Comment: Use `torch.from_numpy()` instead of `torch.FloatTensor()` When dealing with numpy arrays it is always recommended to use `torch.from_numpy()` To make the dimensions same use `reshape`

Comment: The 'torch.reshape' worked great! Thanks